# excel 2003 etc. web query “treat consecutive delimiters as one”, how to shape a query in such way in the (excel 2016) “Power Query”

Tags: excel

Excel 2003 etc. web query offers to **group a single row whose columns are different than above or below, essentially.**

But so far I see no INTUITIVE or "wizard-guided" way to shape a query in such a way with the new Office 365 (excel 2016) "Power Query", neither saw I anything on the topic in cursory skimming of superficial help documentation,

and while I can work around this issue (on the spreadsheet itself where I am already doing relatively extensive post-query processing,) it is far easier using the wizard!

Seems the wizard configuration is "**treat consecutive delimiters as one**" in excel 2007 options dialogue of "edit query" (also of found when making a new query in excel 2007 etc. versions).

**How can I do this in Office 365** without manually constructing a "synthetic" or home-made "query" via left(), right(), and mid() formulae tactical stuff on the grid itself (the old school super excel finesse & monstrosity of it!! as much fun as it is!)

***Thank you so very much!***

miscellanea and detail:

Not sure if it is the browser or stack overflow doing the spell check but it cites etc. as a misspelling, and offers to replace it with etc. LOL =^)

I am pulling from a simple html that is local, and is a funky annoying table spat out by  software I wish I had more control of, so it is a web query.

I suppose I could edit the html file prior to pulling it in excel, but this would defeat the point of making this as simple as possible and as FAST as possible.  Ideally if I new how to just scrape the data looking at the guts of the software I wish I controlled more of, without exporting to html, I'd love to watch all the dependant models flicker (the data *can be* relevant on an microsecond basis) live with the live data it is based on, but alas, one thing at a time, minding redundancy bloat etc....

Answer (score 0):

Since my company upgraded to Excel365(ver 1803), I had the same problem when importing/getting data from txt (CSV) with space delimiter(one or more  consecutive).

However, Excel365 is still having the previous import wizard  on "Text to Columns" function, but this function requires all the text in a single column.

Though I am still looking for a power editor solution, paste the plain text on a spreadsheet and Excel automatically uses consecutive spaces as a column delimiter.